# jQuery .toggle() only shows, never hides an absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Please don't forget to upvote the great answer by my eventual savior Beetroot-Beetroot!**

I've got this problem where `.toggle()` only shows on click, it never hides.

TL;DR: It normally looks like the screenshot below but the `.toggle();` doesn't hide when I click a *second* time.

The first div appears on a mouseover of the actual select box, taking any clicks it would receive on itself.

Normally clicking the first div which is the small div with 1px black border will show the second div, which works, and clicking again will hide it, which doesn't work.(the click event works, the toggle fails)

[image: screenshot]

Here's the html of the elements, yeah it's normally within a table cell:

```
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
<select class="placeholder0" id="sortedselect0">
<option selected="selected">- for - </option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; foraminated</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; foraminiferous</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; foraminous</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; forbearant</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; forbearing</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; forbidden</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; forbiddenly</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; forbidding</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; forblack</option>
<option>adj. &nbsp; forby</option>
<option>AND MANY MORE OPTIONS</option>
</select>

<div class="anti" id="anti0" style="height: 18px; width: 179px; position: absolute; top: 209px; left: 494px; border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: black; border-right-color: black; border-bottom-color: black; border-left-color: black; border-image: initial; background-color: transparent; display: block; "></div>

<div class="floats" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 227px; left: 494px; border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: black; border-right-color: black; border-bottom-color: black; border-left-color: black; border-image: initial; " id="floatdiv0"><img style="width: 222px; height: 342px;" alt="" src="fake_iframe.png"></div>
```

Then the javascript which follows it directly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//make original select box unselectable
jQuery(".placeholder0").mouseover(function() {
    var pos = jQuery(this).position();
    var width = jQuery(this).outerWidth();
    var height = jQuery(this).outerHeight();

    jQuery("#anti0").css({
        height: (height - 2) + "px",
        width: (width - 2) + "px",
        position: "absolute",
        top: pos.top + "px",
        left: pos.left + "px",
        border: 1 + "px solid black",
        z: 2,
        "background-color":"transparent"
    });
});

jQuery("#floatdiv0").unbind('click');

jQuery("#anti0").live('click', function(){

    // .position() uses position relative to the offset parent,
    // so it supports position: relative parent elements
    var pos = jQuery(this).position();

    // .outerWidth() takes into account border and padding.
    var width = jQuery(this).width();
    var height = jQuery(this).height();

//first hide any other fake selects
jQuery("div.floats").hide();
//and antiselect overlays
jQuery("div.anti").hide();

//unhide current antiselect overlay
jQuery("#anti0").show();

    //show the menu directly over the placeholder
    jQuery("#floatdiv1").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: (pos.top + height) + "px",
        left: pos.left + "px",
        border: 1 + "px solid black",
        //padding: height + "px",
        z: 1    
    });
    jQuery("#floatdiv1").toggle();
});

//hides the menu  
jQuery("#floatdiv1").mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery("#floatdiv1").hide();
    //and unhide overlays
    jQuery("div.anti").show();
});
</script><br>
</td>
```

I threw the .unbind in there just to try, I'm not even sure what it's for I'm afraid.

Same happened with live, just .click was fine.

//hides the menu was my old way of hiding the div window, just leaving it, which worked flawlessly.

I was considering resorting to

```
{
    if ( showOrHide == true ) {
        jQuery('#floatdiv1').show();
    } else if ( showOrHide == false ) {
        jQuery('#floatdiv1').hide();
    }
}
```

but I tested it and it didn't work so perhaps I'm doing it wrong?

I wanted to add an example of the problematic code at work but somehow [mister problem.php](http://www.thehappymarquis.com/misterproblem.php) is completely not working when I copy the code from the usual pages to this new php page.

Please help me just toggle this div one way or another. >.<

Comment: Can't you sum it for us?

Comment: wow, sea of border properties o_O

Comment: oh yeah I forgot to tell, the jQuery adds those border properties on the 2 divs, they're both hidden at start

Comment: please provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/TDQDH/, but this one malfunctions just like [mister problem.php](http://www.thehappymarquis.com/misterproblem.php), I'll make a tl;dr hold on

Comment: @gdoron tl;dr in place, sorry for information bombing you guys xD

Comment: Who the hell downvoted and WHY? care to explain please? =S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some assumptions ...

Inside the click handler :

```
jQuery("div.floats").hide();
...
jQuery("#floatdiv1").toggle();
```

As `#floatdiv1` also has `class="floats"`, the nett effect of the command sequence above will always be to show it.

Try :

```
jQuery("div.floats").not("#floatdiv1").hide();//hide all other floats
...
jQuery("#floatdiv1").toggle();//toggle this float
```

Comment: it works! only problem I'm left with is the fact that `//and unhide overlays
  jQuery(\"div.anti\").show();` isn't activated now ofc, any idea how I do that **depending on what the toggle outputs**?

Comment: Try replacing the two lines `$("div.anti").hide();` and `$this.show();` with the single line `$("div.anti").not($(this)).hide();`.

Comment: that's indeed smoother but the problem is that as the mouseover creates all the anti divs http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3xmanUCgp1qizmrao1_250.png they are all hidden after a click, because for some reason even with z-indez they'd overlap my floatdiv. So I need to restore their opacity/unhide them after I close the floatdiv to be able to click them.

Comment: I've been upvoting some of your other answers as a thanks btw =)

Comment: @Happy, I'm close to visualizing the issue. Could you possibly reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: M.E. or something similar - they don't know.

Comment: I'm afraid I fail to, for some reason the it stops working correctly in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/635fX/

Comment: I don't know what M.E. stands for, I'm not native English speaking =S

Comment: the problem comes down to: how do I fire an unhide all .anti when .toggle() is hiding the floatdiv (and not when it's showing floatdiv)

Comment: @Happy, I can achieve what you suggest [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TDQDH/3/), but it doesn't work 100%. When the floatdiv is hidden it is not available to be clicked and the default action of the placeholder occurs.

Comment: Hopefully I'll be awake enough to have a look at this tomorrow(it's going to be a short night for me I'm afraid), anyhow you've been an amazing help! much thanks, it's greatly appreciated! =)

Comment: oh forgot to mention! I implemented your piece of if code with the right adjustments and it works flawlessly! =)